# CORB blocking Google Places API call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to implement custom google places autocomplete and my browser (Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106) is blocking my request while calling their API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) is written that this API can be used both server & client side. The API key is correct. What am I missing? 
[CORB Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHs3l.jpg)

Comment: You mis-read the page you linked to. The service can be used both client-side and server-side, but the way you use it is different. Follow the link where it says 'If you're building a client-side application...', you get here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: @peeebeee you are totally right, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORB blocks a response that has JSON, HTML or XML inside. It's a security measure. In order to achieve what you desire is not by ajax calls. When attaching the maps script tags, inside the script you have to mention which libraries you want to use, and it will be imported in the DOM. Afterward, you have to generate the object and do the filtering.

Ex: So instead of doing ajax calls for a finding places you call the constructor and pass the arguments.

```
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDI2Fgh7xK7JfbUXTVSundJUNfIpHITbTY&libraries=places&callback=operationalMap"></script>
var places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map),
    populateMapWithMyLocation = [//array with geolocation lat & lng];

populateMapWithMyLocations.forEach(function(result){
    places.getDetails(result, function(response){                            
        console.log(response)
    })
});
```

P.S.: Use the same approach for the photo library, nearby search, text search.